# my first jQuery slider I need some advice please

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build my own customer slider from scratch, I got very very BASIC knowledge of jQuery.

What I am trying to accomplish is the following: I would like to build a slider with paragraphs with testimonials. My controls will be "next" and "prev", however I would like to do this dynamically. I have no idea how many paragraphs I will have since they are pulled out of the DB. So it could be 1 or 10, that is my problem. I managed to show() and hide() my divs on click but that is all.

Here is my basic code:

**jQuery**

```
$("#testimonials").ready(function(){

$("#1").show();
$("#2").hide();
$("#3").hide();

  $("#next").click(function(){
     $("#1").hide();
     $("#2").show();
                    });

  $("#prev").click(function(){
     $("#2").hide();
     $("#1").show();
                    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="testimonials">
   <div id="1" class="active-slide">
       <p>This is paragraph one</p>
   </div>
   <div id="2" class="inactive-slide">
       <p>This is paragraph two</p>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="inactive-slide">
        <p>This is paragraph three</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am open for any suggestion or if someone know a good tutorial to read to accomplish this.

Would it be better if I used UL and try getting "next" by looking for child? I'm sort of brain dead at the moment and can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of slider you want to make ? could you show some live example ?

Comment: Here is the sample: idea is to show 1 at a time and hide all the rest .. http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/9G8SH/   I could do it if it wasn't dynamically loaded ... I have a while loop that creates the DIV tags with all testimonials from the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so firstly having `id`s being numbers is invalid html but with modern browsers I suppose that is not an issue. Secondly you cannot hardcode stuff like that. It means that you will have to write code for each slide, which is not just going to be a pain in the butt, but also doesn't look good. Here I've put up a simple example for you to view

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q4cy3/1/)

Basically you set up the `next` and `prev` functions to work as a system, having a variable containing the current slide being viewed and the nubmer of total slides you can easily calculate which slide is to be shown next or previous. I hope this helps and don't be afraid to ask any more questions you may have in the comments I'll be glad to help you out. Good luck!

Comment: TY this is exactly what i am trying to do, I know I am not suppose to hard code the ID's it was just for practice I was trying to figure out the functions first but at 4:30 am its kid of hard :)... TY so much I will work on this and hopefully get it

Comment: Yes question, why is there 2x next.click ? 1 is function and other one calls the function? could you give me a crash course as to why?

Comment: @LJ-C oh yes, I thought I should have added comments to the demo. That is to initialize the slider at the start. This is also why `visible_slide` is set to `-1` instead of `0`, so that when the initializing runs a value of `1` will be added to `visible_slide` so `-1+1` is equal to `0` and that is the slide that's gonna be shown

Comment: Ok, I understand now that makes sense. Thank you for helping! :) So first part hides it all and sets the slides to -1 so when it gets to the next CALL it will start from one. TY got it :)

Comment: @LJ-C You're welcome! You can also have this functionality multiple ways, you can have an initializing function that handles the initializing and then you wont have to call `next`, but I suppose this is a more efficient way. If I can use what I already have and achieve what I want why not use it, right? `:D`

Answer (score 1):

Please change `$('#testimonials').ready` to `$(#testimonials').load` ( if you are trying to trigger a function when a div is loaded).

[Why it is better ?](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/div-readyfunction-is-this-possible/)

Comment: I have read your link thank you! Still trying to wrap my head around it. My first go I appreciate the effort of helping me out. Thank you Bala

Comment: @LJ-C Glad I could help. The work shown by php_nub_qq is a good one to stick with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

without using separate `ID` for each div

**jQuery**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       function showHide(opt) {
          var current = $(".active-slide");
          var gHelem  = (opt == "next") ? current.next(".testimonials_each") : current.prev(".testimonials_each");
          if(gHelem.length > 0) {
            gHelem.removeClass("inactive-slide").addClass("active-slide");
            current.removeClass("active-slide").addClass("inactive-slide");
          }
       }

      $("#next").click(function(){
          showHide("next");
      });

      $("#prev").click(function(){
         showHide("prev");
      });
   });
```

**css**

```
.inactive-slide {
  display:none;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="testimonials">
   <div class="testimonials_each active-slide">
       <p>This is paragraph one</p>
   </div>
   <div class="testimonials_each inactive-slide">
       <p>This is paragraph two</p>
    </div>
   <div class="testimonials_each inactive-slide">
        <p>This is paragraph three</p>
   </div>
  <button id="prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/eCabIkUl/1/edit)